# AngularJS PHP - track by $index (Undefined Variable)

Tags: php, angularjs, undefined, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJS and php.

I'm attempting to use 'track by $index' to get around ng-repreat:dupes problem and I am getting 'Undefined Variable' for $index.

```
<div ng-repeat='merchandise in merchandiseCtrl.basket track by $index' class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-3'>{{ merchandise.name }}</div>
                        <div class='col-sm-3'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control input-sm'  value='{{ merchandise.quantity }}' ng-model=' merchandise.quantity'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-3'>{{ merchandise.price }}</div>
                        <div class='col-sm-3 '>
                            <button ng-click='merchandiseCtrl.removeItem(merchandise)' type='button' class='btn btn-link btn-xs'>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
```

Can anyone recommend a way around this? - I assume the problem is caused with the file being .php ...

Comment: same problem here. one feasible way t avoid this is to move all these into a single html template. @CottonSocksBro, have you solved it or not?

Comment: You should post your javascript.